# \end{Document} No Line Here to End

Tags: sectioning, document-classes, document-configuration

I keep getting an error:

```
line 44: There's no line here to end. \end{document}
```

This error does not happen when I use the `\maketitle` command instead of `\begin{document}`environment.

Can anyone suggest what I need to change please?

```
%Preamble
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=25mm, right=25mm,top=30mm,bottom=25mm,headheight=34.5pt]{geometry} %Formats page
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} %Allows images
\graphicspath{ {images/} } %Sets image folder location
\usepackage[useregional,showdow]{datetime2} %Allows dynamically updating date
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage,color} %Headers and Footers
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{91,155,213} %Defines Light Blue colour for use
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{\textcolor{lightblue}{
    \title{\bfseries{XXX: Xxxx 12 Xxxxxxxxx Xxxxxxxxxxx - Xxxxxxxxx 1}}\\ 
    \author{Xxxx Xxxx Xxxxxx Xxxxx}\\
    XXX: 12345678 $\vert$ XXX: 12345678}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\sffamily{$\thepage$ of $\pageref{LastPage}$}}

\fancypagestyle{empty}{\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\fancyhead{} \fancyfoot[C]{$\thepage$ of $\pageref{LastPage}$}}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %Changes document default font to Helvetica

%Document Information
\title{XXX: Xxxx 12 Xxxxxxxxx Xxxxxxxxxxx - Xxxxxxxxx 1}
\author{Xxxx Xxxx Xxxxxx Xxxxx}

%Document Content
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    Some Text
\end{titlepage}

%\maketitle
%\clearpage

\section*{Question 1}
\setcounter{page}{2}
test

\section*{Question 2}
test

\section*{Question 3}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is the `\fancyhead` statement. Note that the `\title` and `\author` commands do not typeset anything, they just define author and title for later use by `\maketitle`. So your `\\ ` commands both end lines containing nothing (*there is no line to end*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the missing line to end is already explained by Jan's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344013/16967). `\title` and `\author` does not set their argument, they store the settings in internal macros `\@title` and `\@author`, which are later used and cleared by `\maketitle`.

Since the title and author are used at several places, macros can be used to avoid redundancy.

Further remarks:

- `\bfseries` and `\sffamily` are font switch commands, which does not take arguments. The argument forms are `\textbf{...}` and `\textsf{...}`.
- I do not see a reason to put the page numbers in math mode. Page numbers are usually set in text mode.
- Since the default font family is set to the non-serif font, `\sffamily` is not needed in the fancy headers/footers.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  left=25mm,
  right=25mm,
  top=30mm,
  bottom=25mm,
  headheight=34.55pt,
]{geometry} %Formats page
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} %Allows images
\graphicspath{ {images/} } %Sets image folder location
\usepackage[useregional,showdow]{datetime2} %Allows dynamically updating date
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage,color} %Headers and Footers
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{91,155,213} %Defines Light Blue colour for use

%Document Information
\newcommand*{\MyTitle}{XXX: Xxxx 12 Xxxxxxxxx Xxxxxxxxxxx - Xxxxxxxxx 1}
\newcommand*{\MyAuthor}{Xxxx Xxxx Xxxxxx Xxxxx}
\title{\MyTitle}
\author{\MyAuthor}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \textcolor{lightblue}{%
    \textbf{\MyTitle}\\
    \MyAuthor\\
    XXX: 12345678 $\vert$ XXX: 12345678%
  }%
}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\fancypagestyle{empty}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhead{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}%
}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

%Document Content
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    Some Text
\end{titlepage}

%\maketitle
%\clearpage

\section*{Question 1}
\setcounter{page}{2}
test

\section*{Question 2}
test

\section*{Question 3}
test

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tink, that your error is, to define the `\title` and `\author` within the definition of your fancyhead.

```
\fancyhead[C]{\textcolor{lightblue}{
    \title{\bfseries{XXX: Xxxx 12 Xxxxxxxxx Xxxxxxxxxxx - Xxxxxxxxx 1}}\\ 
    \author{Xxxx Xxxx Xxxxxx Xxxxx}\\
    XXX: 12345678 $\vert$ XXX: 12345678}}
```

This are definitions, which shouldn't be defined within the defintion of your fancy head.  (Some lines later, you use those two commands again.)

While setting the `\title` in `\fancyhead`, you don't produce a line of output.  Instead, you store the contents of {} into a variable, which will be used later on.  Hence, you can't use `\\` as linebreak.  There is no such line before the `\\`!

Bye

Jan